# Angularjs set selectbox value after clicking on a button

Tags: html, angularjs

I am having some troubles resolving this problem; so when i click on a button, i need to have my select box populated by the exact value :

i explain : 
 in this code i have my select box (view html) :

```
<label for="tag" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Paramètres</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="editTag" required>
        <option ng-repeat="tag in listTags" value="{{tag}}" ng-disabled="affectDisabled(tag.disabled)">{{tag.libelle}}</option>
      </select>         
    </div>
```

in my view i need the value="{{tag}}" and not value="{{tag.libelle}}" because i am using this model in another function where i need the object with all its properties.
and here is my button :

```
  <li ng-repeat="var in tagStyles">
     <button type="button" class="btn label-info btn-xs" ng-click="editionModifierTag(var)">
                      <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"/>
                      </i>
     </button>
    </li>
```

when it is clicked the directive ng-click triggers the function editionModifierTag(var) that takes a parameter.

and here is my function in the controller :

```
$scope.editionModifierTag = function(parameter) {
    for (var i = $scope.listTags.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (parameter.tag === $scope.listTags[i]._id) {

            $scope.listTags[i].disabled = false;
            $scope.temp = {};
            $scope.temp.libelle = parameter.tagName;
            $scope.temp._id = parameter.tag;
            $scope.temp.__v = 0;
            console.log('temp ===>');
            console.log($scope.temp);
            $scope.editTag = JSON.stringify($scope.temp);
            console.log('editTag ==>');
            console.log($scope.editTag);

            $scope.policeList = parameter.police;
            $scope.tailleList = parameter.taille;
            $scope.interligneList = parameter.interligne;
            $scope.weightList = parameter.styleValue;
            $scope.colorList = parameter.coloration;


        }
    }






};
```

in this function i am setting $scope.editTag to the value of the tag that is clicked in the button, but the select box is not displaying the value.

can anyone help me with this

Comment: TL;DR but you should probably consider using ngOptions instead of <option> with ngRepeat. More here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Comment: Is the console.log($scope.editTag) output OK ? You bound your ng-repeat on $scope.listTag but I don't see when it's modified. Could you make a simple plunker?